# ENOTEMPTY error when I run npm run dev in my Nuxt3 project

Tags: node.js, vue.js, npm, nuxtjs3

When I run `npm run dev` I get this huge error message:

> npm ERR! code ENOTEMPTY
> npm ERR! syscall rename
> npm ERR! path /home/pavel/Documents/Web Projects/twitter-clone/node_modules/@babel/parser
> npm ERR! dest /home/pavel/Documents/Web Projects/twitter-clone/node_modules/@babel/.parser-IknzzFET
> npm ERR! errno -39
> npm ERR! ENOTEMPTY: directory not empty, rename '/home/pavel/Documents/Web Projects/twitter-clone/node_modules/@babel/parser' -> '/home/pavel/Documents/Web Projects/twitter-clone/node_modules/@babel/.parser-IknzzFET'

Comment: Your node module have a trouble with babel, try to delete the folder node_modules (if you can do it in comand line is much faster), after that just run `npm run build` and retry your server.

Comment: Still doesnt fix that unfortunately. It says that I need some index.js file. Here are the logs:
Cannot start nuxt:  Cannot find module '@babel/parser'                                                                  21:12:09
Require stack:
- /home/pavel/Documents/Web Projects/twitter-clone/index.js

Comment: In your package.json what is the version for babel ?